# Issues with regex in CPP

Tags: c++, regex

I've got some issues with regex and C++.
My problem is that with the same expression, some strings that should match doesn't.

```
RX: ([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]|_][[:digit:]])
INPUT: a&3
REGEX not MATCH

RX: ([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]|_][[:digit:]])
INPUT: u#5
REGEX not MATCH

RX: ([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]|_][[:digit:]])
INPUT: o@9
REGEX MATCH
```

can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

the code I use is this:

```
bool parse(string &in){
string st;
try{
st = remove_beginning_whites(in);
}catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
    return false;
}

//if (st!="")   cout << st;
try{
    char rx[]={"([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]|_][[:digit:]])"};

    cout << "RX: "<< rx<<'\n'<<"INPUT: "<<in<<"\n";
    regex my_RX (rx);

if (regex_match(in,my_RX)) 
    cout<<"REGEX MATCH\n\n"; 
else 
    cout<<"REGEX not MATCH\n\n";

} catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        cerr<<e.code()<<'\t';
        cerr<<e.what()<<"\n\n";

}
return true;

}
```

and this is the 'remove_beginning_whites' function:

```
string remove_beginning_whites(string& in){
auto pos = in.find_first_not_of(" \n\r\t");

if(pos==string::npos) {
                        throw std::invalid_argument("empty string");
                        }
else                {
                    return in.substr(pos);
                    }
}
```

I'd like also to know what's different between '[[ ]]' and '[ ]'

Comment: Most probably you fail to remove all initial/trailing whitespace. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/BpMEJP) showing your strings are matched.

Comment: Try with `char rx[]={"\\W*([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]_][[:digit:]])\\W*"};`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. I got what the problem was: Strings are terminated by \r [x0D], and my regex wasn't looking for that 'extra character' (buy I still don't understand why it sometimes went OK). So really thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confirm that some strings you had end with a CR (carriage return). Since `regex_match` requires a full string match your regex cannot work as they do not match the traling CR symbol.

As a workaround, you may just add an optional `\r?` at the end of the pattern:

```
char rx[]={"([[:alpha:]][^[:digit:]_][[:digit:]])\r?"};
```

The `?` modifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern.